# Why do we include the variance of $\epsilon$ for the variance of predicted values? (normal linear models)

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, variance, prediction-interval

Suppose I have a normal linear model $Y = X\boldsymbol{\beta}+\epsilon$, $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^{2}I_{n})$. Given covariates $x_{*}$ and estimated parameter vector $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$, I wish to find:

- The variance of a point estimate $x_{*}^{T}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$
- The variance of the mean estimate, also $x_{*}^{T}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$

My question is -- why do we include the variance of $\epsilon$ for finding the variance of a point estimate? And why do we only need to consider the variance in $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ for the mean estimate?

Comment: The only random component if the model is the error term.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Hi, I would much appreciate more elaboration as I've been trawling through the Internet for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for the mean estimate in a linear regression does not include the error term (it has been "expected valued out" [since it has mean zero]).

The source of variance in the mean estimate comes from the betas (which are estimates and have their own sampling distribution).

Point estimates require the full linear equation, including error term. That is why it contributes extra variance over and above the mean estimate variance.